# Socket with cordova does not upload file to server

Tags: node.js, sockets, cordova

I am trying to send a file type from my cordova application, using node's socket.io-client, and both the server and the client do not perform any action or print consoles.

I am using cordova v 10.0.0, socket.io-client v 2.5.0 on the client side, and socket.io 2.4.0 on the server side.

Comment: Fix this problem, sending the file in Blob format, not sending with "new File" instantiated, File has problems in cordova application for some reason.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.